# Spring boot service getting called once per openshift pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Boot / Feign / Openshift service A making a rest call to service B. Service A is running on 1 pod, service B running on 2. Both pods of B are receiving the request from A - only only one should. I would have thought the load balancer chooses one pod and not both. Can anyone explain why this would be happening?

Comment: As you've described it, that does seem unusual, but you haven't really included enough details to potentially understand why.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I agree with David Maze, this seems not only unusual,  but arguably impossible: The TCP/IP semantics wouldn't let one consumer communicate with multiple backends at the same time. More information, ideally a reproducer, is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check documentation which style of load balancing it uses as default.

> The default implementation is entirely iptables-based, and uses
> probabilistic iptables rewriting rules to distribute incoming service
> connections between the endpoint pods.

[Openshift Service Proxy Mode](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html)

Comment: If service B is receiving the request in its 2 pods, would that mean it's not a deliberate load balancer configuration? Because by definition, the LB is used to balance load - not replicate it.